# MYSQL Server 5.5.62 has failed on Windows 64bit operating system

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The configuration operation to starting the server has failed , It cannot executed

below, is the information about the failures in the **log** tab

Attempting to start service MYSQL55...
Failed to start service MYSQL55.
Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 5.5.62 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 3: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 4: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 5: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 6: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 7: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 8: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 9: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 10: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Failed to connect to MySQL Server 5.5.62 after 10 attempts.
Ended configuration step: Starting the server

[image]

Comment: Can you try starting the server outside workbench? Can you check the start up logs to see what the failure is? Try the event log.

Comment: That's the just installer or workbench log. It basically says "Can't start service, can't connect". You need to find logs created by the MYSQL55 service. These are probably in Windows's Event Viewer.

Comment: i am just a beginner,and i am currently installing the mysql,  please could you help and provide where to go too, where can I start the server?

Comment: In the start menu search for "Event Viewer". I think you want Windows Logs, Application. Hopefully there will be some logs near the top from the MYSQL55 service, or something else about the MYSQL55 service, with more information.

Comment: Or to retry starting the service, search start menu for "Services". MYSQL55 should be in the services list and you can trigger a start from there.

Comment: @rups am on event viewer..which folder logs to check?,custom view, windows logs and applic and service logs is showing

Comment: I think you want either "Windows Logs", "Application" or "Windows Logs", "System". But they should all be sorted most-recent first, so you could have a look at them all at about the right timestamp.

Comment: i have the viewed  the "Services", the MYSQL55 was not showing there

Comment: OK, then maybe the problem is that it failed to install the service in the first place. I'm surprised by that, that the installer didn't detect that and show you an error before. However 5.5 is very old: do you really need that? Can you try a more recent version?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue in the configuration stage post installation of mysql.
I had renamed the windows service from `MySQL80` to `MySQL Server 80`. I went back and reverted the service name in MySQL installer. 
This error resolved. 
I also went to service.msc and disabled the duplicate service `MySQL Server 80` since `MySQL80` service had also been created.

Answer (score 1):

Installed the lasted version solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to fix it is to cancel the installation at that point and then just open the mySQL Workbench.

From there you click Local Instance MySQL80 (or whatever it it called for you). Usually this prompts for a password but if you are experiencing this error it wont.

Notice the navigator on the left and click "Users and Privileges". From there select "root" and it will give you the option to change the password. Change the password, apply and restart mySQL. Issue fixed!

TLDR: Quit installation -> Open MySQL Workbench -> Local Instance -> Users and Privileges -> root -> Change password, apply and restart